# Create new column from an existing column with pattern matching in R

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to add a new column based on another using pattern matching. 
I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566343/create-a-new-column-in-a-r-dataframe-using-pattern-matching), but not getting the desired output.

I want to create a new column (SubOrder) based on the GreatGroup column. 
I have tried the following:

```
SubOrder <- rep(NA_character_, length(myData))

SubOrder[grepl("udults", myData, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  "Udults"
SubOrder[grepl("aquults", myData, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  "Aquults"
SubOrder[grepl("aqualfs", myData, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  "aqualfs"
SubOrder[grepl("humods", myData, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  "humods"
SubOrder[grepl("udalfs", myData, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  "udalfs"
SubOrder[grepl("orthods", myData, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  "orthods"
SubOrder[grepl("udalfs", myData, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  "udalfs"
SubOrder[grepl("psamments", myData, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  "psamments"
SubOrder[grepl("udepts", myData, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  "udepts"
SubOrder[grepl("fluvents", myData, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  "fluvents"
SubOrder[grepl("aquods", myData, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  "aquods"
```

For example, I'm looking for "udults" inside any word, such as Hapludults or Paleudults, and return just "udults".

EDIT: If anyone wants to take a shot at  alistaire's comment, this is the search patterns I would use.

```
 subOrderNames <- c("Udults", "Aquults", "Aqualfs", "Humods", "Udalfs", "Orthods", "Psamments", "Udepts", "fluvents")
```

Example data below.

```
myData <- dput(head(test))
structure(list(1:6, SID = c(200502L, 200502L, 200502L, 200502L, 
200502L, 200502L), Groupdepth = c(11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 21L, 22L
), AWC0to10 = c(0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12), AWC10to20 = c(0.12, 
0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12), AWC20to50 = c(0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 
0.12, 0.12, 0.12), AWC50to100 = c(0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 
0.15), Db3rdbar0to10 = c(1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43), 
    Db3rdbar10to20 = c(1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43), Db3rdbar20to50 = c(1.43, 
    1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43), Db3rdbar50to100 = c(1.43, 
    1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43, 1.43), HydrcRatngPP = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), OrgMatter0to10 = c(1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 
    1.25), OrgMatter10to20 = c(1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 
    1.25), OrgMatter20to50 = c(1.02, 1.02, 1.02, 1.02, 1.02, 
    1.02), OrgMatter50to100 = c(0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 
    0.12), Clay0to10 = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8), Clay10to20 = c(8, 
    8, 8, 8, 8, 8), Clay20to50 = c(9.4, 9.4, 9.4, 9.4, 9.4, 9.4
    ), Clay50to100 = c(40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40), Sand0to10 = c(85, 
    85, 85, 85, 85, 85), Sand10to20 = c(85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85
    ), Sand20to50 = c(83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83), Sand50to100 = c(45.8, 
    45.8, 45.8, 45.8, 45.8, 45.8), pHwater0to20 = c(6.3, 6.3, 
    6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3), Ksat0to10 = c(23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23
    ), Ksat10to20 = c(23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23), Ksat20to50 = c(19.7333, 
    19.7333, 19.7333, 19.7333, 19.7333, 19.7333), Ksat50to100 = c(9, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 9), TaxClName = c("Fine, mixed, semiactive, mesic Oxyaquic Hapludults", 
    "Fine, mixed, semiactive, mesic Oxyaquic Hapludults", "Fine, mixed, semiactive, mesic Oxyaquic Hapludults", 
    "Fine, mixed, semiactive, mesic Oxyaquic Hapludults", "Fine, mixed, semiactive, mesic Oxyaquic Hapludults", 
    "Fine, mixed, semiactive, mesic Oxyaquic Hapludults"), GreatGroup = c("Hapludults", 
    "Hapludults", "Hapludults", "Hapludults", "Hapludults", "Hapludults"
    )), .Names = c("", "SID", "Groupdepth", "AWC0to10", "AWC10to20", 
"AWC20to50", "AWC50to100", "Db3rdbar0to10", "Db3rdbar10to20", 
"Db3rdbar20to50", "Db3rdbar50to100", "HydrcRatngPP", "OrgMatter0to10", 
"OrgMatter10to20", "OrgMatter20to50", "OrgMatter50to100", "Clay0to10", 
"Clay10to20", "Clay20to50", "Clay50to100", "Sand0to10", "Sand10to20", 
"Sand20to50", "Sand50to100", "pHwater0to20", "Ksat0to10", "Ksat10to20", 
"Ksat20to50", "Ksat50to100", "TaxClName", "GreatGroup"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: To make your code a lot DRYer, make a vector of your patterns (and replacements, if they're different), and use `sapply` to call `grepl` or `gsub` or whatever you like.

Comment: I attempted something similar with : subOrderNames <- c("Udults", "Aquults", "Aqualfs", "Humods", "Udalfs", "Orthods", "Psamments", "Udepts", "fluvents")
but got lost in the machine 0o0o0

Comment: With a `for` loop, `pat <- c('udults', 'aquults', 'aqualfs', 'humods', 'udalfs', 'orthods', 'psamments', 'udepts', 'fluvents', 'aquods'); for(x in 1:length(pat)){SubOrder[grepl(pat[x], myData$GreatGroup, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  pat[x]}` Make a second vector for replacements and substitute it for the second `pat[x]` if you need.

Comment: Or more directly, `myData$SubOrder <- myData$GreatGroup; for(x in pat){myData$SubOrder <- gsub(paste0('.*', x, '.*'), x, myData$SubOrder, ignore.case = TRUE)}`. If there's no match in this case, it's left with the value of `GreatGroup` instead of `NA`, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few options, some of which I posted in the comments above.

**Note:** All options assume the replacement for the strings that match patters are just the pattern. If you want something else, they're all easily editable to include separate replacement values.

### Option 1: `for` + `grepl`

Using the same code as the original, but looping to avoid repetitive code:

```
# make a list of patterns
pat <- c('udults', 'aquults', 'aqualfs', 'humods', 'udalfs', 'orthods', 'psamments', 'udepts', 'fluvents', 'aquods')

SubOrder <- rep(NA_character_, length(myData))

for(x in 1:length(pat)){
  SubOrder[grepl(pat[x], myData$GreatGroup, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  pat[x]
}
```

---

### Option 2: `for` + `gsub`

Build the new column in place by copying `myData$GreatGroup` and then altering it with `gsub`. The extra regex pasted on includes characters within the same string.

```
myData$SubOrder <- myData$GreatGroup
for(x in pat){
  myData$SubOrder <- gsub(paste0('.*', x, '.*'), x, myData$SubOrder, ignore.case = TRUE)
}
```

Note that values not matched by one of the strings in `pat` will have the value from `GreatGroup`, not `NA`. If you want them to be `NA`, fix them with

```
myData$SubOrder[!(myData$SubOrder %in% pat)] <- NA
```

---

### Option 3: named list + `stringr::str_replace_all`

My favorite because it doesn't loop, although it requires the `stringr` package (which is pretty awesome, anyway).

Make a named list from `pat`, where the name is the regex you want to replace, and the item is the string to match:

```
l <- as.list(pat)
names(l) <- paste0('.*', pat, '.*')
```

so it looks like

```
> l
$`.*udults.*`
[1] "udults"

$`.*aquults.*`
[1] "aquults"

$`.*aqualfs.*`
[1] "aqualfs"
......
```

Then use `str_replace_all` to DO IT ALL AT ONCE:

```
myData$SubOrder <- str_replace_all(myData$GreatGroup, l)
```

Boom.

**Note 1:** `str_replace_all` doesn't have an `ignore.case` option, but you can wrap `myData$GreatGroup` in `tolower` (easy) or reconfigure the regex (hard).

**Note 2:** Like **Option 2**, it leaves unmatched entries as the value from `GreatGroup`, so use the line at the end of that option to go back to `NA`s, if you like.

Comment: +1 for Option 3... though now it doesn't work with named lists, just named vectors `names(pat) <- paste0('.*', pat, '.*')` and then `myData$SubOrder <- str_replace_all(myData$GreatGroup, pat)` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myData$SubOrder[grepl("udults", myData$TaxClName, ignore.case = TRUE) | grepl("udults", myData$GreatGroup, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  "Udults"
```

You can add as many columns to the filter as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using dplyr, but you probably need to create a giant nested ifelse statement...

```
library(dplyr)

myData %>%
  mutate(SubOrder = ifelse(grepl('udults', GreatGroup, ignore.case = T), 'Udults',
                           ifelse(grepl('aquults', GreatGroup, ignore.case = T, 'Aquults',
                                        ###  All of the other ifelse statements
                                        ifelse(grepl('fluvents', GreatGroup, ignore.case = T), 'fluvents', 'aquods')
                           ))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a function that successively substitutes each pattern, which avoids repeating your code over and over. Note that with this approach, if a given string matches more than one pattern, the first pattern in the substitution sequence will be the one that gets used.

```
# multi-grepl function adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/15254254/496488
mgrepl <- function(pattern, replacement, x, ...) {
  if (length(pattern) != length(replacement)) {
    stop("pattern and replacement do not have the same length.")
  }
  result <- x
  for (i in 1:length(pattern)) {
    result[grepl(pattern[i], result, ...)] = replacement[i]
  }
  result
}

# Patterns and replacements
pat = c("udults","aquults","humods","fluvents")
repl = c("Udults","Aquults","humods","fluvents")

SubOrder =  mgrepl(pat, repl, myData$GreatGroup)

SubOrder

[1] "Udults" "Udults" "Udults" "Udults" "Udults" "Udults"

# Or, if you want to add this as a new column to the data:
myData$SubOrder = mgrepl(pat, repl, myData$GreatGroup)
```

One additional note: One issue with the code in your question is that you referenced the whole data frame, rather than the column you want to substitute:

```
SubOrder[grepl("udults", myData, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  "Udults"
```

should be changed to

```
SubOrder[grepl("udults", myData$GreatGroup, ignore.case = TRUE)] <-  "Udults"
```

**UPDATE:** Regarding your comment, see the code below. The function does replace both values with "Udults".

```
myData$GreatGroup[1] = "Paleudults"

myData$GreatGroup

[1] "Paleudults" "Hapludults" "Hapludults" "Hapludults" "Hapludults" "Hapludults"

mgrepl(pat, repl, myData$GreatGroup)

[1] "Udults" "Udults" "Udults" "Udults" "Udults" "Udults"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in my code. Also, it appears this code returns the pattern as the replacement. I would need to be able to search for 'udults' in multiple words such as Hapludults, Paleudults, and just return udults for both.

Comment: See the update to my answer. The code in my answer seems to be doing the correct thing as far as I can tell.